# ¿Cómo puedo guardar cadenas de texto a una variable en Prolog?

Tags: prolog

tengo este código en Prolog:

```
inicio:- CAD is "hola",
write(CAD).
```

Estoy haciendo pruebas ya que tengo que hacer un proyecto que me permita manejar distintos archivos dependiendo de las veces que se haya corrido el programa, y tenía la idea de manejarlo con una variable. Me sería de gran ayuda si me guiaran.

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que quieres lograr? así podría ser más directo ayudarte.

Answer (score -1):

no queda claro que es lo que buscas, si te refieres a asignar un string en una variable cualquiera, usas el operador de unificacion '='

```
X = "Esto es una string".
```

ahora, si quieres guardar una cadena ingresada desde reclado, para eso esta la sentencia read

```
read(Cadena), write(Cadena).
```

saludos.

Comment: Responder al azar sin saber cual es el problema no es una buena práctica. En vez de eso espera a tener 50 de reputación y poder añadir comentarios para pedir aclaraciones o hacer preguntas.